# One foreign key referring to multiple table's primary keys

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, schema, primary-key, rdbms

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKMCR.png) **<1 - image>** One foreign key referring to multiple table's primary keys.

**<1.1>** Where **primary1** table has two columns **primary1_id int(11)** and **first_name varchar(10)** in which **primary1_id** is a **primary key**.

**<1.2>** Same as **primary1** table,  **primary2** table has also two columns **primary2_id int** and **last_name varchar** in which **primary2_id** is a primary key.

**<1.3>**Also there is a **foreign1** table has two columns **foreign_id int** and **full_name int** in which **full_name** is a **foreign key** which is referring to multiple table's **primary keys** like **primary1_id** and **primary2_id**.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQlKv.jpg) **<2 - image>** This **foreign key**,  **full_name** only allow to insert those values which are same in both **primary1_id** and **primary2_id** columns.

**<2.1>** So if I enter five entries in **primary1** table and four entries in **primary2**.

**<2.2>** In which **primary1_id's** are set as 1 to 5 and **primary2_id's** are set as 1 to 4.

**<2.3>** But why this **foreign key full_name** is allowing me to enter **1 to 4** only which are available in both primary key's tables?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain what you mean by "useful". You seem to be using "relation" (wrongly) for "relationship" in its sense of FK (foreign key). What does the source of these designs say about them? What do & don't you understand? A FK says values must appear elsewhere as a PK/UNIQUE. Why is that not enough to know? [Please use text for text, do not use images/links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).

Comment: "Foreign key constraints only show that primary ids which are available in common in all primary key constraints tables" is not clear. Please write it more clearly. Use more words & sentences; refer to things clearly; don't try to cram it into one sentence. Try translate.google.com, it is lately better via AI.

Comment: Hi. When you say "why", I *guess* you know that the *FKs* say full_name values must appear as PKs, so I *guess* you mean, what sort of *business situations* would have a design like that? But you don't actually clearly say. (See also other parts of my last comment.) I *guess* you made up those column names because in everyday life it doesn't make sense that each full name be restricted to being both a first & last name. But each of my teammates has to be both among the athletes & and the adults. PS See how sqlvogel's answer presents a table in a concise, standard & even formal way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unusual in my experience but it potentially makes sense as a way to implement certain business rules with a meaning similar to "A must be both B and C".

One possible example: a StaffDiscount table identifying customers who are also employees and are eligible for a discount. Such a table might have a single foreign key that references both the Customer table and the Employee table. This does assume that a common key is used to identify both customers and employees.

```
CREATE TABLE StaffDiscount
 (CustomerEmployee INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY /* Same key identifies customer and employee */,
  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerEmployee) REFERENCES Customer (CustomerNum),
  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerEmployee) REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeNum));
```

Comment: Added some example SQL

Comment: i have got somewhat similar challenge, I have 2 columns `type` and `refid`, so i want `refid ` which is a foreign key that refers to table that `type` has, so basically i want `type` to decide what table will `refid` refer ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in case  when one is going to create relation between more than one table. As presence of foreign key shows existence of all related tables with that table. And helps in retrieval of data from that environment at a single relational query.